# vspackage: how could I make a command in the context menu available for specific file type

Tags: vspackage

in the solution explorer, there are projects and files. and I want my custom command only to show up when user right click on certain file type, let's say ".cs" or ".html". How could I make so happen?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your package is loaded, you can control the visible/enabled state of a command through the [BeforeQueryStatus event of the OleMenuCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.olemenucommand.beforequerystatus.aspX).

In the event handler you set if the command is supported (OleMenuCommand.Supported property) the visible state (OleMenuCommand.Visible property) and enabled state (OleMenuCommand.Enabled property) etc. according to whichever conditions, such as the type of file selected in Solution Explorer.

Comment: thanks Carlos, when I want to vote up for you, I was told needing at least 15 reputation to vote.